# What is the food that James Woods eats in "Best Seller" (1987)?

Tags: food-identification

This is a screenshot of the food. What is it?

[image]

It appears in the original movie in at 49:28.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a) it requires access to an external resource that may not always be available & b) is likely to be of interest to only the original asker.

Comment: I replaced the video link with a screenshot. It is indeed bad etiquette to require people to go watch a video somewhere out on the Internet, especially on a page bugging people to create an account. Also, the film happens to have a nude scene less than 30 seconds before the plate comes on, and with the search bar covering 2 hours of video, it is hard to catch the plate without it. And finally, I would be very surprised if the hosting site has a license for the movie.

Comment: Please do not re-edit the link to the video into the post - it is quite iffy given that it is probably a pirate copy, and there is no need to see the actual movie when a closeup screenshot is available.

Comment: @Toteigs I had to delete two of your comments for verbal attacks on other users, and lock the question because you continued re-editing it with unacceptable content. Please read our Code of conduct, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/conduct, before posting anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are [canapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canap%C3%A9): little bites of something tasty. Being served on a silver tray implies they are expensive and were made with care and time, letting us know that this setting (I know nothing about the movie and haven't followed your link) is rich and luxurious.

The black blobby stuff is probably supposed to be caviar, the white piped stuff probably some sort of creamy filling. The red could be fruit, or a red caviar / salmon roe kind of thing. (It would be odd to have sweet and not-sweet on a tray together.) Other visible garnishes include sprigs of parsley and "cheeks" of olives. The beige cylinders are probably puff pastry or bread and the green ones probably carved cucumber. A comment on the other answer points out you could use a fluted cookie cutter to cut both bread and cucumbers, and that seems really likely in a catering context. [In movie-set reality these things might be play dough or mashed potatoes or anything else a prop person feels like using.] Would you need more detail than that? Why?

Comment: Please watch the actual movie link because I think the green thing that he eats appears to be sugar candy of some kind.

Comment: I actually like your interpretation of caviar - the cucumbers are very likely to be filled with black and red caviar side-by-side.

Comment: A canapé is always on bread. If they're sweet they could be considered petit fours, savoury would be amuse gueule. The latter pair are both types of amuse bouche… none of which tells us what might be in these particular snacks, hence my vote to close the question [even though the OP has added a helpful picture since then].

Comment: @Tetsujin "Traditionally, canapés are built on stale bread (although other foods such as puff pastry, crackers, or fresh vegetables may be used as a base" - from the wiki link I provided. Most people I know aren't pedantic about it and call little savoury bites canapes regardless of their base. You are technically right though (the best kind of right.)

Comment: @KateGregory Thanks Kate. I believe you are right about the green things. They appear to be cucumbers topped with red and black caviar. –

Answer (score 3):

This is an appetizer plate made from vegetables.

1. The light green stumps are cucumbers. The reddish filling is not recognizable from this angle and size. *Update* As Kate Gregory noted in her answer, a combination of red and black caviar is a very likely candidate.
2. The "roses" are carrots. *update* after consulting a vintage garnish book, apparently there are cooks dexterous enough to make these out of tomatoes. So, there is some possibility that it is a different vegetable of a similar color.
3. There are some bites of dip (it's impossible to tell the ingredients from a picture, although there is a high chance that it is dairy-based) served on pieces of vol au vent, garnished with olives and parsley. *update* after comments, the base might be bread instead. I want to believe that I am seeing horizontal striations, but the resolution is not high enough to confirm it one way or the other.
4. There are a few chives around the plate circumference, as garnish
5. The light pink flower in the middle is an orchid blossom, used as a decoration only.

Comment: Incorrect.  The green things are sugar pastries of some kind with some kind of strawberry-like thing on it.

Comment: @Toteigs It would be most unusual to have a sweets plate made to imitate a standard-looking vegetable appetizer/canapé plate. While people do such kind of thing in our Instagram-first age, this was not done in 1987. Also, such imitations tend to be recognizable when one has the opportunity to look at them long and close enough. These look way too realistic, and in the context, they cannot be anything but cucumbers.

Comment: I'd guess i's a base of bread / toast cut with possibly the same cookie cutter as the cucumber (enlarged the screenshot as much as I could) instead of vol-au-vent, but apart from that, I agree with everything.

Comment: @Toteigs If you can’t deal with [community edits](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/editing) and abide by the [Code of Conduct](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/conduct), you will not enjoy your time here much.